# Converter Imagem String em Bitmap Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Tenho uma aplicação que envia fotos, essas fotos são armazenadas no banco (SQL Server) em um varchar(max) como um texto.
Até aí tudo ok.

Agora preciso converter esse texto todo em Bitmap e mostrar essa imagem em um Image do Delphi (Versão Delphi 7)

Parte do "Texto" da imagem é algo assim;

> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
>   AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
>   AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAGYATIDASIA
>   AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
>   AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3
>   ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm
>   p6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEA
>   AwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx
>   BhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK
>   U1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3
>   uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD8gdIu
>   bW4RWtrmCZSQwaKRHDMS+AvzbjnHHzMMdGyBXdWUIYYwSTtHI4Iyx+8Dkk7W2+5HICEn5G0XUHs8
>   Pbko25RmPAAC7hGx+Ydk2nBGCQQSxOfUNJ8Y6jGP+PliowSG2kZBY5zuIGMDr7At/E3zsY2i9Ltp
>   X031atFNbrRtvpdtE80e/wCfn3fl+Wt3d/SdhGSvbI28qpBViz4I2nGMKRngDAXJIYHrrOL8WwBw
>   pbaS3DDJVeRjPHQnLkgivn7SvHtwgzMYWXPzD5VYksVIUEsdpPzL1A4O4AZr0HSfiDbA5khAAAVs
>   SAlWy2GbLEbgcZJ+UMWw2eDm4tN3etur7N2lo7P0V3a2qdkNNPZr+rrZu/2X/m938W/8FONE+0/B
>   vwdrSrk6X4ztoPNwdyxX+m6nGwZyTzvgh+U8hduTnYa/Nj9kv4NeFPjj8Qtd8GeKbq/tseC9e1XR
>   X0+VI5H1jT/srwCYFXMkIjMzvGuGfagDYBNfqj+3ZqreOfgXN4Z0Dw3retarPq2l6jA2nWbXUViN
>   PuGad7jyizos0LyiLERVpMfP5gAr81/2LNf074ZftFaBq/jm8HhjRodK8R2OqXOrLLYxwreaPeQQ

Answer (score 4):

O que está salvo é, aparentemente em base64.

Se for mesmo base64 então, você pode utilizar essas funções (créditos [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909096/convert-base64-to-bitmap) no SOEn )

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Soap.EncdDecd;

function Base64FromBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap): string;
var
  Input: TBytesStream;
  Output: TStringStream;
begin
  Input := TBytesStream.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.SaveToStream(Input);
    Input.Position := 0;
    Output := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.ASCII);
    try
      Soap.EncdDecd.EncodeStream(Input, Output);
      Result := Output.DataString;
    finally
      Output.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Input.Free;
  end;
end;

function BitmapFromBase64(const base64: string): TBitmap;
var
  Input: TStringStream;
  Output: TBytesStream;
begin
  Input := TStringStream.Create(base64, TEncoding.ASCII);
  try
    Output := TBytesStream.Create;
    try
      Soap.EncdDecd.DecodeStream(Input, Output);
      Output.Position := 0;
      Result := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        Result.LoadFromStream(Output);
      except
        Result.Free;
        raise;
      end;
    finally
      Output.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Input.Free;
  end;
end;

var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  s: string;

begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  Bitmap.SetSize(100,100);
  Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  Bitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(20, 20, 80, 80));
  s := Base64FromBitmap(Bitmap);
  Bitmap.Free;
  Bitmap := BitmapFromBase64(s);
  Bitmap.SaveToFile('C:\desktop\temp.bmp');
end.
```

Comment: Isso, a forma em que a imagem se encontra é base64.
Usando essas funções, ocorre um erro no Delphi 7 na declaração da variavel: **Output: TBytesStream**, não sei qual uses eu uso para essa situação?

Outro erro que ocorre também, é na hora do uso dessa expressão: **TEncoding.ASCII**
Obrigado

Comment: Alguem tem mais alguma dica para resolver isso?

Comment: `TByteStream` vem de System.Classes ou Classes dependendo da versão do delphi http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Classes.TBytesStream  já o `TEnconding` vem da sysutils http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_TEncoding.html

Comment: @user11890 Utilizando os **uses** citados funcionou?