# é possivel deixar o label e texto em 90 graus?

Tags: delphi

É possível fazer um `TLabel` ficar na vertical, porem seu texto dessa forma:

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já testei alguns componentes, mas não funcionam na versão do Delphi-XE8.

Consegui deixar ele em 90 graus porem os números saem um embaixo do outro

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui da seguinte maneira.
Adicionar o texto em uma imagem igual a ideia do @Júnior

com o código abaixo.

```
procedure TForm2.ConvTextOut(CV: TCanvas; const sText: String; x, y,
  angle: integer);
var
  LogFont: TLogFont;
  SaveFont: TFont;
begin
  SaveFont := TFont.Create;
  SaveFont.Assign(CV.Font);
  GetObject(SaveFont.Handle, sizeof(TLogFont), @LogFont);
  with LogFont do
  begin
    lfEscapement := angle *10;
    lfPitchAndFamily := FIXED_PITCH or FF_DONTCARE;
  end;
  CV.Font.Handle := CreateFontIndirect(LogFont);
  SetBkMode(CV.Handle, TRANSPARENT);
  CV.TextOut(x, y, sText);
  CV.Font.Assign(SaveFont);
  SaveFont.Free;
end;

ConvTextOut(Origem.Canvas, label1.caption, 0, 0, 0);
  Resultado.Width := Origem.Height;
  Resultado.Height := Origem.Width;
  Resultado.Update;
  for k := 0 to Origem.Width do
    for Y := 0 to Origem.Height do
      Resultado.Canvas.Pixels[Origem.Height-Y, k] := Origem.Canvas.Pixels[k,Y];
```

Unica coisa que não ficou 100% ao meu ver, foi que o tamanho do caption dentro da imagem não ficou um tamanho legal.

Answer (score 4):

Você não pode rotacionar o componente `TLabel` (até onde descobri), você pode encontrar por ai componentes que suporte esse comportamento, o **FireMonkey** é capaz de gerar esse efeito!

Porém, segue um procedimento que pode clarear suas ideias e talvez chegar onde deseja!

Implemente isto no `OnPaint` do formulário!

```
var
  lf: TLogFont;
  tf: TFont;
begin
  with Form1.Canvas do
  begin
    Font.Name := 'Arial';
    Font.Size := 24;
    tf        := TFont.Create;
    try
      tf.Assign(Font);
      GetObject(tf.Handle, SizeOf(lf), @lf);
      lf.lfEscapement  := 320;
      lf.lfOrientation := 320;
      SetBkMode(Handle, TRANSPARENT);
      tf.Handle := CreateFontIndirect(lf);
      Font.Assign(tf);
    finally
      tf.Free;
    end;
    TextOut(10, Height div 2, 'Texto Rotacionado aqui!');
  end;
```

De uma olhada no **FireMonkey**, você pode encontrar algo que posso ajudar mais ainda!

Se não resolver, você pode copiar a `String` e gerar uma imagem no (`TImage`), rotacionar e posicionar no local do `TLabel`.

Segue pergunta e resposta de como fazer a conversão da String para Imagem:

[Aqui mesmo do SObr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25064/converter-imagem-string-em-bitmap-delphi)